# setTargetObjectId

Tags: apex, trigger

Apex code:

```
public class Anu {
    //static method
    public static List<Booking__c> sendEmail(List<Booking__c> bookings) {

        //query on template object
        EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'BookingConfirm'];

        //list of emails
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        //loop
        for(Booking__c boo : bookings){

            //check for Account
            if(boo.Email__c!= null){

                //initiallize messaging method
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                //set object Id
                singleMail.setTargetObjectId(boo.OwnerId);

                //set template Id
                singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);

                //flag to false to stop inserting activity history
                singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

                //add mail
                emails.add(singleMail);

               //This will not send email to contact  
                         }
        }

        //send mail
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

        return bookings;

}

}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger BookingTrigger on Booking__c (after insert) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter){

        if(Trigger.isInsert ){ 

            //helper class for single email but bulk messages
            Anu.sendEmail(trigger.new);
        }
    }

}
```

In this,singleMail.setTargetObjectId(boo.OwnerId); which id should be placed. Actually i want to trigger mail on booking custom object but mail is not triggering. Could you please help me to resolve the error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Target Object Id will be Contact, lead, or user Id to which the email will be sent. Which is looking correct.

If you are using sandbox please check.

Setup > Deliverability > Access level = 'All Email'